# "Preparing Your Desktop" interferes with Windows 7 GUI?

Tags: .net, winapi, windows-7, startup

I have a .NET program (targeted to 3.5 Client Profile) that creates a new administrator account, reboots, then automatically logs in as that account using the AutoAdminLogon registry value. Before it reboots it sets the RunOnce to run again at startup. Once the computer reboots and logs in, the program is supposed to hide the Start Orb and the Task Bar and go fullscreen.

The problem is that on reboot there is a message of "Preparing Your Desktop", supposedly for the newly created administrator account. My program continues to run in the background, but when the "Preparing Your Desktop" screen finishes the Task Bar and Start Orb are not hidden. Why would this be? Every subsequent restart the Task Bar and Start Orb are hidden correctly, but then the "Preparing Your Desktop" screen doesn't appear again.

I'm using this method to hide the Task Bar and Start Orb:

```
IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
IntPtr orb = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)0xC017, null);
ShowWindow(orb, SW_HIDE);
```

The FindWindow, ShowWindow, and FindWindowEx methods are in win32.dll.

So I guess my final question is: does the "Preparing Your Desktop" screen somehow block Windows UI elements from being shown or hidden? If, for example, the UI hasn't even been created so as to be shown or hidden, how can I wait until the loading screen is done and then run my program?

Comment: If you don't want the taskbar or Start button, then why are you bothering to run Explorer at all? This is like buying a cheeseburger and then complaining that it's hard to pick off all the cheese.

Comment: Would not allowing Explorer to run have any adverse effect on the .NET GUI that needs to show? If not that could solve my problem.

Comment: Only you can say whether your program has a dependency on Explorer. It sounds from the description that you have a kiosk program, in which case you should do kiosk-like things. Explorer does not support having its windows manipulated in this way.

Comment: Alright. Looks like I'm going to have to study up on how to do things outside Explorer to be able to do this right.

Answer (score 1):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that the FindWindow fails because at the point of "Preparing Your Desktop" there is no `Shell_TrayWnd` to be found. This would make the first ShowWindow fail, as would the FindWindowEx and successive ShowWindow on that handle.

You should be testing the return values of **all** API calls, always, before just assuming they worked and blindly continuing to execute your code. For instance, the documentation for [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that if it fails, the return value is `NULL`:

> **Return value**
>
> Type:
>
> Type: HWND
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the window that has the specified class name and window name.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Comment: Understood, which is why there's error-checking in the actual code. And also why there's a second question that I asked pertaining to your point about "Shell_TrayWnd" not existing yet. I would just put the code in a while loop checking for null, but I'm not sure how that would affect the Windows startup process.